# How to make an array like this

Tags: c#, arrays

```
List<Customer> c= new List<Customer>()
{
    new Customer{Id = 1, Name = "Bruce"},
    new Customer{Id = 2, Name = "John"}
};
```

I just  know

```
c.ForEach(o => str += o.Id.ToString() + ",");
```

Any ways to make it simple?

I just wanna get Id out and make Ids array  `int[] Ids = new {Id = 1, Id = 2}`

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal this is not new to C# 4.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal this [has always been possible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.concat(v=vs.71).aspx) because the `String.Concat` method that the `+` compiles down to supports a `(string, object)` overload.

Comment: No need to convert Id to string to concatenate with another string. You can write o.Id + "," and it will not give error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to create an array with all those ids then you can use [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) and [`ToArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx) methods :

```
int[] ids = c.Select(i => i.Id).ToArray();
```

Comment: hey Please help me..the same issue I have faced  I am used Viewbag to display data in array like this  `var visitorsData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.arrayVistiors));` but i want to get like `var visitorData = {US:200,IN:123}`  like this.. Please help how to get through this. @Zbigniew

Comment: @Brij hard to tell without knowing your data structure, but it looks like you want to have some kind of dictionary. Try using `ToDictionary` e.g. `arrayVisitors.ToDictionary(key => key.CountryCode, value => value.VisitorsCount)`

Comment: @Brij on the other hand you may just as well do this: `arrayVisitors.Select(i => new { i.CountryCode, i.VisitorsCount })`